# Editable pages approach

Tags: asp.net-mvc, design-patterns, architecture

I'm working on application with some sort of CMS features. I need some pages to be editable. For instance:

- you can edit a text block right in your browser
- you can add and remove different modules to your page

For instance, if I have a main page I may want to edit welcome text.

If I have a sidebar I may want to add/remove new modules to the sidebar such as:

- email subscription module
- social network (facebook, twitter, etc) links block
- text block

My application may have several pages, not only one.

I want to keep it simple and I'm looking for the right approach/examples/existing tools.

What's the best pattern / third-party solution for ASP .NET in order to implement this and keep it simple?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use ASP.NET MVC I think the best solution is to look into Orchard.  It's really easy to get up and running, has a rich set of existing modules and building a module from scratch is really easy.  This was actually started by a couple of Microsoft guys and then spun out into it's own open source project.  http://www.orchardproject.net/